# Making a script which opens 3 cygwin terminals and executes the command (windows)

Tags: bash, shell, batch-file, cmd, cygwin

- What I am trying to do:

Make a script which opens 3 **cygwin** terminals **in windows**, and each cygwin terminal should navigate to specific directory and run `source .env` command, then run `npm start`

What I am able to do so far is execute the command in bat script:

Terminal #1) `cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop\node-service-1 && echo "source .env" && npm run start`

Terminal #2) `cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop\node-service-2 && echo "source .env" && npm run start`

Terminal #3) `cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop\node-service-3 && echo "source .env" && npm run start`

Instead I want to do the same thing but in cygwin and keep the cygwin open.

---

The reason is because source .env doesn't work when I don't use cygwin.

Comment: Please confirm or revise: are you running a terminal emulator like `mintty` with an interactive `bash`? and from there you want to execute a `bash` script that launches 3 more terminals with separate start directories? Within each terminal, looks like you want to run `bash` to interpret `.env` plus execute `npm` as a child process, right? Should each bash and terminal exit after `npm` exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you want to create a new bash session and run some setup commands initially and then keep the bash session open. That you start it in a new terminal here, is not so important.

I would (mis-)use your `~/.bashrc` for it, and an environment variable to communicate whether to start a service, and if yes, which one it is: At the end of your .bashrc, do a

```
if [[ -n $node_service ]]
then
  ns_dir=/cygdrive/c/Users/Username/Desktop/node-service-$node_service 
  if [[ -d $ns_dir ]]
  then
    cd $ns_dir
    echo source .env # What's the purpose of this?
    npm run start
  else
    echo "ERROR: Directory '$ns_dir' does not exist"
  fi
  # Make sure that npm is not run again in a bash subshell
  node_service=
fi
```

With this setup, you can write a Windows batch script, doing something like:

```
set node_service=1
start c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /usr/bin/bash -l -i
```

for each node. I used here mintty as an example, but you can adapt this for whatever terminal program you are using.

Comment: I tried this, but when I run the batch script by double clicking so it just opens up the terminal and doesn't do anything. Should I type something in the terminal after it opens up?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman : First open a terminal cmd window, and then type the batch script I suggested. It should at least output a useful error message. You can also execute `/usr/bin/bash -l -i -x`, which should give you a trace of the commands executed by bash on startup.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman : I just verified: At least with `mintty`, you don't need to write `start`. On my system, the effect is the same with our without `start`, but I suggest that you remove it for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create three (3) files. The first two (2) belong in the user's Cygwin home directory. The third one, a .bat script, can be anywhere.

=== ~/.env === C:\cygwin64\home\username\.env

```
export AVAR=something
```

=== ~/doit.bash === C:\cygwin64\home\username\doit.bash

```
cd $(cygpath -u $USERPROFILE)/Desktop/$1
echo source ~/.env
echo npm run start
```

=== trycyg.bat

```
FOR %%A IN (node-service-1 node-service-2 node-service-3) DO (
    START "node1" "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -i ~/doit.bash %%~A
)
```

Comment: I tried this, but whenever I click on trycyg.bat so it keeps opening the terminal and closing instantly. Then I opened cmd and navigated to trycyg.bat file, and then tried opening up using `start trycyg.bat` then it opened another cmd in which it says this: ``` C:\Users\Username\Desktop>FOR %A IN (node-service-1) DO (START "node1" "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -i ~/doit.bash %~A )

C:\Users\Username\Desktop>(START "node1" "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -i ~/doit.bash node-service-1 )

C:\Users\Username\Desktop>
```
But then nothing else happened

Answer (score 1):

You can save following script in test.sh and run it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd C:/Users/Username/Desktop
for service in node-service-1 node-service-2 node-service-3; do
    cd $service && cygstart bash -c "source .env && npm run start" && cd -
done
```

To troubleshoot, run following commands :

```
cd C:/Users/Username/Desktop
cd node-service-1 && bash -c "source .env && npm run start" && cd -
```

Comment: Whenever I try to run the file `./test.sh` so it just opens up a terminal and closes instantly.